# How do I draw horizontal bars in a chart using Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I'm beginner with the Core Plot framework. Right now, I am able to render bar charts on the screen.

However, I need to draw a horizontal bar chart that has the bars extending from the Y axis, like so:

```
 ^
y|
 |****
 |*******
 |**********
 |******
 |---------------> x
```

How would I implement such a horizontal bar chart in Core Plot?

Comment: actually i thought of adding image but unable to do it.to be in clear i need to draw the bars perpendicular to screen i.e in portrait mode.hope u got me now!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you said you are using core-plot, there are sample codes with the framework, in which barChart has been implemented. You can have a look at it.

EDIT:

Sorry I saw you update now, and I got you need horizontal bars. Use following code.

```
CPBarPlot * barPlot = [CPBarPlot ...];
[barPlot setBarsAreHorizontal:YES];
```

Comment: yeah sure vaibhav!,and more over how to interact with the bar charts.for example i need a popup or similar kind of thing when i ouch one of the bars from them...

Comment: hi how to interact with the bars in the barchart?

Comment: @ravoorinandan can you please put the code for the above graph. I want to draw same graph.

Comment: @Apple: Can you please downlaod the latest code base of core-plot from code.google as it might be ARC enabled now.