# How to draw horizontal bar graphs without showing axises

Tags: ios, ipad, graph, core-graphics

I need to implement a horizontal bar graph similar to the one shown below. Here I don't need to show axises along with the graph, still I need to imagine there is one:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: As with your previous question, Core Plot would be the way I recommend to do this, and both of these issues have been addressed before within it: ["How do I draw horizontal bars in a chart using Core Plot?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429635/how-do-i-draw-horizontal-bars-in-a-chart-using-core-plot) and ["Don't Display the Axis line in bar chart using core plot"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469267/dont-display-the-axis-line-in-bar-chart-using-core-plot).

Comment: @BradLarson Is it possible to show the names over the bars as shown? How can I implement that?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this by using 
 UIBezierPath with CAShapeLayer

You can use the following function to draw an horizontal bar

```
    func drawLine(startpoint start:CGPoint, endpint end:CGPoint, linecolor color: CGColor ,  linewidth widthline:CGFloat){        
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(start)
    path.addLineToPoint(end)

    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = widthline

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
```

How to call this function in swift is

```
    let start = CGPoint(x:20,y:100)
    let end = CGPoint(x:200,y:100)
    //red part of line

   drawLine(startpoint: start, endpint: end,linecolor:       UIColor.redColor().CGColor,linewidth:11.0)
```

You can find out complete code in here

http://bestarticlesall.blogspot.com/2014/12/draw-horizontal-bar-chart-using-swift.html